# Using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to solve for a function

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to find a valid $f$ in this, knowing $x>0$ and $a>0$

$$6+\int_a^x \frac{f(t)}{t^2}dt=2\sqrt{x}$$

Applying the FCT i have:
$$6+\frac{f(x)}{x^2}=2\sqrt{x}$$
so $$f(x)=(2\sqrt{x}-6)x^2$$

Is this solution valid? I also need to calculate for my $f$ which $a$ is valid.
I think every positive $a$ is valid, but i don't understand why my book ask this if i already know $a>0$

Comment: Why only take the derivative on one side?

Comment: FCT is for deriviative.  You did the derivative of the integral, but not of the $6$ nor of the $2\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Solution is valid for $a=9$.

Comment: @alans How did you calculate the $a$?

Comment: @Marco From qbert answer and initial equation is $6+\int_a^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}dt=2\sqrt{x}$, from where is $6+2\sqrt{x}-2\sqrt{a}=2\sqrt{x}$ or $a=9$.

Comment: An easy way to calculate $a$ (without calculating $f$!) is to plug in $x=a$, noting that the integral then vanishes, leaving you with the equation $6 = 2\sqrt{a}$.

Comment: @qbert No, $f(t)=t^\frac{3}{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't apply the differential operator to both sides of the equation!

Taking
$$6+\int_a^x \frac{f(t)}{t^2}dt=2\sqrt{x}$$
You can use the fundamental theorem of calculus as follows, with $d$ the differential operator, a fancy way of saying take the derivative of both sides:
$$
d(6+\int_a^x \frac{f(t)}{t^2}dt)=d(2\sqrt{x})\\
\Rightarrow \frac{f(x)}{x^2}=\frac{2}{2\sqrt{x}}\\
\Rightarrow f(x)=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x}}=x^{1.5}
$$
edit: fully answering the question and following @Joey Zou 's suggestion above you can take $a=x$ to eliminate the integral (by integrating over an interval of length zero) leaving
$$
6+\int_a^a \frac{f(t)}{t^2}dt=2\sqrt{a}\Rightarrow \sqrt{a}=3\Rightarrow a=9
$$

Comment: Sure! And how can I calculate the valid $a$?

Comment: No, not every $a$ works - if you change $a$, you obviously change the value of the integral, but not the value of $6$ or of $2\sqrt{x}$. To find the correct value of $a$, perform the integration with (for example) $x = 1$ and solve for $a$.